# Find longest Palindrome substring

Tags: c++, algorithm, strings, interview-questions, palindrome

I am preparing for technical interview and I found this question on [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-palindromic-substring-set-2/), but I did not understand their solution. So, I have written my own solution. I want to optimize this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool isPalindrome(std::string& str)
{
    for (int i = 0, j = str.length()-1; i<j; ++i, --j)
    {
        if (str[i] != str[j])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int longestPalindrome(std::string& str, std::string& palindromeStr)
{
    int max = 0, start = 0, end = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < str.length(); ++j)
        {
            std::string sub = str.substr(i, j);
            if (isPalindrome(sub) && max < sub.length())
            {
                max = sub.length();
                start = i;
                end = j;
            }
        }
    }
    palindromeStr = str.substr(start, end);
    return max;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "forgeekskeegfor";
    std::string palindromeStr;
    std::cout << longestPalindrome(str, palindromeStr) << '\n';
    std::cout << palindromeStr << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code is reasonably clear and obvious, but has some severe inefficiencies.

First, let's pick up some simple oversights.  Both `isPalindrome()` and `longestPalindrome()` ought to have internal linkage (using either the `static` keyword or the anonymous namespace), and the `str` arguments should be reference to const:

```
namespace {
    bool isPalindrome(const std::string& str);
    int longestPalindrome(const std::string& str, std::string& palindromeStr);
}
```

In passing, we can simplify the interface of `longestPalindrome()`.  It doesn't need to return the string and its length; if we simply return the longest palindrome, then obtaining the length is trivial:

```
    std::string longestPalindrome(const std::string& str);

    // main() can now look like:
    //   std::string palindromeStr = longestPalindrome(str);
    //   std::cout << palindromeStr.size() << '\n';
    //   std::cout << palindromeStr << '\n';
```

The next oversight is that `std::string::length()` returns a `std::size_t`, so don't compare it with (signed) `int`:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0, j = str.length()-1; i<j; ++i, --j)
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note that I've left a bug there (that's neatly missed because we always call this with a non-empty string): if `str.length()` is zero, then `j` starts at a very large positive value (because the subtraction is unsigned, and wraps).

BTW, there's a neat way to test a string for symmetry (at the expense of repeating the initial comparisons), using `<algorithm>`:

```
static bool isPalindrome(const std::string& str)
{
    return std::equal(str.begin(), str.end(), str.rbegin());
}
```

---

Now to the matter of efficiency.  We're creating new string objects for every possible substring of the input.  That's a lot of copying.  We could reduce that by using `std::string_view`.

That's only part of the way towards an efficient solution, though.  We really need to change the algorithm.  My recommendation is to iterate over each character as a possible mid-point of an embedded palindrome, and at each position, determine what's the longest palindrome possible from there (in most cases, it will be 1 or 2 chars).  There's no need to consider longer substrings centred on that position once you have a failing case, so that eliminates much of the unnecessary work we're doing here.

Hint: for this we can use `std::make_reverse_iterator()` and `std::mismatch()`.

---

Finally, the single test we have in `main()` isn't really enough.  At a minimum, we want examples of odd- and even-length palindromes, and also check that we handle the trivial case of empty string as input.

---

## Update - using iterators

I've developed the idea I hinted at in the second section; there's probably a little more scope for reducing duplication:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

namespace
{
    template<typename Iter>
    // requires BidirectionalIterator(Iter)
    void updateBest(Iter forward_start,
                    Iter forward_end,
                    std::reverse_iterator<Iter> backward_start,
                    std::reverse_iterator<Iter> backward_end,
                    std::string_view& best_so_far)
    {
        auto span = std::mismatch(forward_start, forward_end,
                                  backward_start, backward_end);
        auto start = span.second.base();
        auto end = span.first;
        std::string_view candidate{ &*start, static_cast<std::size_t>(std::distance(start, end)) };
        if (candidate.size() > best_so_far.size()) {
            best_so_far = candidate;
        }
    }

    std::string_view longestPalindrome(const std::string& str)
    {
        std::string_view best_so_far;

        // Work out from the middle of the string
        auto const halfway = (str.size() + 1) / 2;

        // first, loop from midpont to end of string (but we can stop
        // when there's no room for a bigger palindrome)
        for (auto i = str.begin() + halfway;  i + best_so_far.length()/2 < str.end();  ++i) {
            // test for odd-length palindrome
            updateBest(i, str.end(),
                       std::make_reverse_iterator(i), str.rend(),
                       best_so_far);
            // test for even-length palindrome
            updateBest(i + 1, str.end(),
                       std::make_reverse_iterator(i), str.rend(),
                       best_so_far);
        }

        // then, loop from midpont to beginning of string (but stop
        // when there's no room for a bigger palindrome)
        for (auto i = str.rbegin() + halfway;  i + best_so_far.length()/2 < str.rend();  ++i) {
            // test for odd-length palindrome
            updateBest(i.base(), str.end(),
                       i, str.rend(),
                       best_so_far);
            // test for even-length palindrome
            updateBest(i.base(), str.end(),
                       i + 1, str.rend(),
                       best_so_far);
        }

        return best_so_far;
    }

}


int main()
{
    for (std::string s: { "",
                "forgeekskeegfor",
                "abc abc",
                "forgeeksskeeg",
                "geeksskeegfor" }) {
        auto palindromeStr = longestPalindrome(s);
        std::cout << "Found palindrome of length " << palindromeStr.size()
                  << " in " << s << ": " << palindromeStr << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: How should I know when to declare a function `static` ?

Comment: If you don't intend a function to be used by any other translation unit (≅ implementation file), then it's a good candidate for the anonymous namespace or `static`.

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid checking *every* string by growing the substring on both ends. That way you can quit the inner for loop as soon as the substring isn't a palindrome anymore and use the previous iteration's substring as the palindrome.

```
if(input_str.empty())return 0;
size_t largest = 1; //if string is not empty then the first character is always a palindrome.
size_t start = 0;
std::string_view view = input_str; //create string view to avoid casting each substr call.
for (int center = 1; center < str.length(); center++)
{
    //even length palindromes
    for (int j = 1; center - j >= 0 && center + j < str.length(); j++)
    {
        if (center - j < 0 || center + j >= str.length() || !isPalindrome(view.substr(center - j, center + j)))
        {
            int length = 2*(j-1);
            if(length > largest){
                start = center - j;
                largest = length;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    //odd length palindromes
    for (int j = 1; center - j >= 0 && center + j + 1 < str.length; j++)
    {
        if (center - j < 0 || center + j + 1 >= str.length() || !isPalindrome(view.substr(center - j, center + j + 1)))
        {
            int length = 2*(j-1) + 1;
            if(length > largest){
                start = center - j;
                largest = length;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Also I use `std::string_view` to pass to `isPalindrome` to avoid allocating a new strings every time. `std::string_view` creates a view into the string and taking the substring of it is a constant time operation with no allocations.

Comment: A further improvement is to start `center` from the middle of the input string and work towards both ends - you can stop when there aren't enough characters before the end to accommodate a longer palindrome than your current best.  That does make the code longer, but some of that can be reduced again when you eliminate duplication.

Comment: This is the insight that people are really looking for during an interview.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that a little optimization could be done by changing the way the substrings are extracted from the main string: the iterations should start from the original string itself and then continue by subtracting characters.

In this way the first time `isPalindrome()` returns `true`, the palindrome is the longest one.

Here is a little edit to your `longestPalindrome` function:

```
int longestPalindrome(std::string& str, std::string& palindromeStr)
{
    for (int len = str.length(); len > 1; len--)  // One-char strings can't be considered as palindromes...
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= str.length() - len; j++)
        {
            std::string sub = str.substr(j, j + len);
            if (isPalindrome(sub))
            {
                palindromeStr = sub;
                return len;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0; // It is not a palindrome...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest restricting to one loop, flatting the rest.
I used the C++17's feature "If statement with initializer" to limit the scope of the variable "current".

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

bool is_palindrome(std::string_view str) {
    return std::equal(str.cbegin(), str.cbegin() + str.size()/2, str.crbegin());
}

std::string_view longest_palindrome(std::string_view str)
{
    auto offset = str.cbegin();
    auto size = str.size();

    while(size > 0) {
        if (std::string_view current = {offset, size}; is_palindrome(current)) return current;
        if (offset + size >= str.cend()) { offset = str.cbegin(); --size; }
        else ++offset;
    }
    return {};
}

int main()
{
    for (std::string str: { "", "forgeekskeegfor", "abc abc", "forgeeksskeeg", "geeksskeegfor", "kayak" }) {
        auto palindrome = longest_palindrome(str);
        std::cout << "Found palindrome of length " << palindrome.size()
            << " in " << str << ": " << palindrome << '\n';
    }
}
```

[Test online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6i3NeSSIJopBYwcA)